# PhoneGap plugin installation like Facebook

Tags: phonegap-plugins

I am new to PhoneGap I have implemented PhoneGap Facebook plugin for Android and iPhone using `phonegap-plugin` and editors like Eclipse and XCode. But I want to know:

Is there any other way of installing plugins using `config.xml` building app with `build.phonegap`?

Answer (score 0):

The PhoneGap people have been talking about adding plugin support to PhoneGap Build for some time, but have not released anything yet. Here is what they were saying around April 2012:

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/_phonegap_build_future_plugin_support